# How do i call jquery function from the view on load if model is not null in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my Jquery function and view. 
Jquery function will call another controller and action name which in presents the partial view.

This is my main View ...i just want to call partial view directly.

```js
            function clickAdd(compid, requestid) {
                debugger;
                var url1 = "/Component/AddEstimate/?compID=" + compid + "&requestID=" + requestid;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url1,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#impactDevEstimateModal").find('.modal-content').removeData(data);
                        $('#impactDevEstimateModal').html(data);
                        $('#impactDevEstimateModal').show();
                        $("#ModalAvailableTemplate").hide();
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        404: function (content) { alert('cannot find resource'); },
                        500: function (content) { alert('internal server error'); }
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        //alert("Error");
                        $('#deStatusMessage').html(getStatusHTML(" Couldn't save data due to internal error. Please try again. ", "Error"));
                    }
                });
            }
```

```html
 <div style="display:none">
        @{
        if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
        {

            @Html.TextBox("template", Model.FirstOrDefault().TypeOfTemplate, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm" })
            clickAdd(@ViewBag.CompID, @ViewBag.RequestID);//not working
        }
        else
        {
        }
}
</div>
```

Comment: try `<script>clickAdd('@ViewBag.CompID', '@ViewBag.RequestID')</script>`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to run a js/jquery function inside your view, try this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/UpdateDetailedEstimates.js"></script>
<script>clickAdd('@ViewBag.CompID', '@ViewBag.RequestID');</script>
```

also you have to add `''` around your @viewbag, for js/jquery to understand it.

```js
function clickAdd(compid, requestid) {
                debugger;
                var url1 = "/Component/AddEstimate/?compID=" + compid + "&requestID=" + requestid;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url1,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#impactDevEstimateModal").find('.modal-content').removeData(data);
                        $('#impactDevEstimateModal').html(data);
                        $('#impactDevEstimateModal').show();
                        $("#ModalAvailableTemplate").hide();
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        404: function (content) { alert('cannot find resource'); },
                        500: function (content) { alert('internal server error'); }
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        //alert("Error");
                        $('#deStatusMessage').html(getStatusHTML(" Couldn't save data due to internal error. Please try again. ", "Error"));
                    }
                });
            }
```

```html
<div style="display:none">
        @{
        if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
        {

            @Html.TextBox("template", Model.FirstOrDefault().TypeOfTemplate, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm" })
            <script>clickAdd('@ViewBag.CompID', '@ViewBag.RequestID');</script>
        }
        else
        {
        }
}
</div>
```

Comment: my jquery is present in other js file..Trying this but function doesn't get a hit.